# Setting multiple global authorization policies on ASP.Net Core controller by route?

Tags: authorization, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-authenticationhandler

Working with an ASP.Net Core API.  There is one route (api/*) for the regular application, another one (admin/*) for the admin api's.  Is there a way to set different global policies based on the URL?

This article [Setting global authorization policies using the DefaultPolicy and the FallbackPolicy in ASP.NET Core 3.x](https://andrewlock.net/setting-global-authorization-policies-using-the-defaultpolicy-and-the-fallbackpolicy-in-aspnet-core-3/) talks about how to set global authorization on different parts of the application (MapRazorPages, MapHealthChecks, etc).

The MapHealthChecks has a parameter for the routes the policy is to be applied.  MapControllers() does not take any parameters.  Is it possible to do the same things on a controller?

Comment: It seems you want to use different policy based authentication for different route prefix? Actually in asp.net core mvc, the default route is controller/action, you can set an authorize attribute to each controller and specific the policy name.

Comment: Rena, yes I know the default authorization route is controller/action, but in this application there will be multiple controllers mapped to api/* and admin/*.  The goal here is to simplify things for the developer.  The developer simply needs to group the different controllers together and they don't have to worry about the attributes anymore..........  As I think about this more, maybe there is wisdom in leaving it at the controller/action level........

Answer (score 0):

The custom policy can be specified separately for each area:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("ApiPolicy", policy =>
    {
        policy.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
        policy.RequireClaim("scope", "api");
    });
});
...
app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "Api",
    pattern: "api/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}")
.RequireAuthorization("ApiPolicy");
```